# Exception in android build. Build error in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Hello I have tried to build an application and send it to an android build but am getting an build error.

This is a small snippet of exception in error log that I got when I put the build onto the server.

```
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Unknown source file : Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
Unknown source file :   ... 12 more
Unknown source file : 1 error; aborting
:preDexDebug FAILED
:preDexDebug (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 56.932 secs.
Starting process 'command '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java''. Working directory: /tmp/build2186746778357232766xxx/Starter Command: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/lib/dx.jar com.android.dx.command.Main --dex --verbose --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --output /tmp/build2186746778357232766xxx/Starter/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-050c44252ac48b6fb75508d313fd95ce08e1abcc.jar /tmp/build2186746778357232766xxx/Starter/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-gcm/8.3.0/jars/classes.jar

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Please find the attached error log 
[image: Error Log 1]
[image: Error Log 2]

Comment: Can you provide the full log? This is missing a bit of information. Also did you change the classpath add native code or did something special?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to us changing the behavior of Google Play Services. We are looking to redeploy the change with a slightly more conservative approach so we would still need the error log to confirm exactly what went wrong.

Comment: I think at that time it was not working. Now it is perfectly working and build is successful. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Hi Shai, I did not try in Android devices later but Still am getting the error as unfortunately the game has stopped but the build was successful this time.

Comment: Please see the one more log which I got when i plugged my physical device and saw the error in DDMS view. The above error was that there was a build error which I got in error log on my dashboard. But this error is after installing the application on the device. Please see the edited post

Comment: Can you copy the text next time instead of a screenshot? We made a few server fixes, can you send a new build and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: No it is still the same . the build is successful but am getting unfortunately the game has stopped error!!!!

Comment: We made another change to the servers, can you see if it resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

same happen for me

Log

```
com.codename1.social.GoogleImpl.init();
                    ^
  symbol:   class GoogleImpl
  location: package com.codename1.social
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 21.094 secs.
```

Comment: That's a question not an answer. See this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/a-thank-you-an-important-update-on-android-builds.html